# How to stop my web page rendering after socket io close

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a NodeJS App with Socket Io integration. Now my web page and app both has been implemented but I am facing one issue during execution:

Below is my web page code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#batch")[0].reset();
var socket  = io.connect('http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx',{'forceNew':true });
socket.on('message', function (data) {
        var newtext = data;
        document.batch.outputtext.value += newtext;
});
socket.on('end', function (data) {
        socket.disconnect();
});
});
</script>
```

And my NodeJS App:

```
exec_script = function(resp) {
      socket.on('connection', function (client) {
      console.log('Connection Established');
      client.on('disconnect', function () {
          console.log('disconnected');
          return;
      });
   var pyshell = new PythonShell('./test.py', options ={ mode: 'text', pythonOptions: ['-u'] });
   pyshell.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    client.emit('message', data);
    console.log(data);
  });
  pyshell.end(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('End Script');
    client.emit('end', 'end');
    client.disconnect();
});
});
};
```

The issue I am facing is that when the Python scripts executes its output is send to browser while my browser status states "Waiting for xx.xx.xxx.xx" and in my FF I see the blue circle circling - that's fine - but even after the Python script has ended and socket disconnected explicitly I still see the browser status as "Waiting for xx.xx.xxx.xx browser title as Connecting with the blue circle rotating?

How can I close and end the connection successfully with the fact that I need the same page in the browser that is I would not navigate the user to some other page?

I tried by using **response.end()** but the issue I am facing is that if the request data was posted as URL form **/today** then calling **response.end()** changes the URL at browser side to **http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx/today** leading to a blank / error page which is what I a do not want in my case - the URL should remain as **http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx**?

Below is the method I am calling my exec_script method:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
   methods.process(req, res);
});

exports.process = function(req, resp) {
    var bname = req.body['date'];
   if(typeof req.body['date'] !== "undefined" && req.body['date'] !== null)
   {
     exec_script(req, resp);
   }
};
```

Comment: From where do you call exec_script? Is it route handler? Can you show code from where it is called.

Comment: That's what i thought. You have completely misunderstood how sockets are supposed to be used. When user request a page, the page loads and connection using sockets is established and remains open until user navigates away. There's no need for router.get or post for sockets to work. You should put the code `socket.on('connection'` outside any route handler. It works independently. You don't even need express.js to talk over sockets.

Comment: Well I changed my code and made the flow in two page - in firdt / one page I take the input from user and other / second page I render the output. I make the user to navigate to first page [I have a Return button to load first page from second page] and when I submit new data I see that previous and current submit output both are being rendered in second page - why the same is occurring? I see the below line :
Connection Established
Connection Established
Connection Established
Again and again when I submit or as many times I submit?

Comment: it's hard to help without seeing more of your code. What I would recommend is put your HTML page in public folder and name it index.html then start your app and go to http://localhost:port/index.html now the connection to sockets should be established. Everything should work and you don't need to go from one page to another. You can talk over sockets since the connection remains open until you close your browse. You can take input from user and display result in the same page